# display of data in aura:iteration lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Hi how to show data in aura:iteration in the below format, attribute is of type strings[].

```
a b
c d
e f
g ..
```

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: @AnnappaPH: i need to show in the given format.   <aura:iteration items="{!v.test}" var="testing">
{!testing} </aura:iteration>

Comment: Then add values to the list like this `<aura:attribute name="test" type="String[]" default="['a b', 'c d', 'e f', 'g ..']" />` and this is just an example do the same in the JS where you are adding values in this `List` instead of adding a single value on a index add two values.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7: a is one data,  b is one data and c and so on. I want to display in above format, its an example which i have shown. U got the question in wrong sense.

Comment: Maybe you are right. So how you are putting data in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `slds grid` system to do this. Firstly study about [Grid in Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#content).

or

you can also achive this using refer [Lightning:layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_layout.htm)

**Sample Code**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <aura:iteration items="['a','b','c','d','e','f']" var="test">
            <span class="slds-size_1-of-2">{!test}</span>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <aura:iteration items="['a','b','c','d','e','f']" var="test">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="6" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="6">
           {!test}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout  >
</aura:application>
```